# Flask server returns 404 on localhost:5000 w/ Twilio

Tags: python, flask, localhost, twilio

I'm following [this guide (Python Quickstart: Replying to SMS and MMS Messages)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey) to try and set up a flask server, but when I try to connect to `http://localhost:5000` I get a 404 error. I can ping 127.0.0.1 no problem.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.message("Hello, Mobile Monkey")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Console output:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
```

[localhost 404'ing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHX4w.png)

Comment: do you see any message in console output ? Do you run browser on the same computer as server ?

Comment: I put everything I see in the console in my post. I do run the browser on the same computer as the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can connect to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` after restarting my computer. Not sure what was causing the issue.

Comment: One obvious difference is that you were using `http://localhost:5000`, but `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` following the restart.

Comment: I tried loading both before restarting, it didn't make a difference.