# 404 Error on Localhost with Twilio + Flask + Ngrok + Python (2.7)

Tags: python, flask, twilio, ngrok

I am following the tutorial from https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-a-text-message-with-python-flask-and-twilio.html.

However after starting up my flask app in one terminal window (`python textapi.py`), starting up ngrok in another terminal(`ngrok http 5000`), copying and pasting the forwarding http url into the twilio console "a message comes in" field, and then texting the number, I am left with a 404 error.

Both my flask terminal as well as my ngrok terminals register the incoming POST but both respond with a 404 error.

My flask app looks like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import pandas
import os

# Load some background data and credentials

app = Flask(__name__)

# Initiate Twilio Client
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    # Do stuff to get response_String
    response = response_string
    resp = twiml.Response()
    resp.message(response)
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Can someone explain where the 404 error is coming from and why it cannot locate "localhost:5000/sms"?

Also this: [Flask server returns 404 on localhost:5000 w/ Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570031/flask-server-returns-404-on-localhost5000-w-twilio) doesn't seem to solve my issue.

UPDATE 1: part of the issue was not having "/sms" at the end of my ngrok url that I pasted into Twilio's console.

Now I'm having an error that twiml has no attribute Response.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. You can find your solution in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44929907/revisions). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You imported [`MessagingResponse`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-python/6.4.2/twiml/messaging_response.m.html) which is what you need to use instead of `twiml.Response()`. So, your code should be:

```
@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    # Do stuff to get response_String
    response = response_string
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(response)
    return str(resp)
```

**Edit**

Just wanted to apologise, the blog post you are referring to was using the version 5 Python library, which did use `twiml.Response`. We've since released version 6 which has the `MessagingResponse` module. There is [a migration document for upgrading from version 5](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python/migration-guide#twiml-generation) which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your URL in your Twilio sandbox in HTTP request

```
http://your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io/sms
```

Here type your URL of localhost.
[image]

[Also check official documentation](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-a-text-message-with-python-flask-and-twilio.html)